# Объекты в javascript

Tags: javascript, объекты

Пишу функцию для игры "камень, ножницы, бумага". Хочу сделать через объект, но возникает проблема, что один из вариантов возвращает undefined. Можете пояснить почему так происходит и как решить эту проблему.
Код программы и фотография консоли приложены.

```
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
    if (p1 === p2) return 'Draw!';
    let obj = {
        'rock': { 'scissors': ['Player 1 won!'] },
        'rock': { 'paper': ['Player 2 won!'] },
        'paper': { 'scissors': ['Player 2 won!'] },
        'paper': { 'rock': ['Player 1 won!'] },
        'scissors': { 'paper': ['Player 1 won!'] },
        'scissors': { 'rock': ['Player 2 won!'] },
    }
    // console.log(obj[p1][p2][0]);
    return obj[p1][p2];
    // console.log(obj["paper"]["rock"]);
};


// console.log(rps('rock', 'rock'));
console.log(rps('rock', 'scissors'));
console.log(rps('rock', 'paper'));

console.log(rps('paper', 'scissors'));
console.log(rps('paper', 'rock'));

console.log(rps('scissors', 'paper'));
console.log(rps('scissors', 'rock'));
```

[image: Логи в консоли браузера]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Смотри. Все достаточно тривиально. Объект не  может иметь  несколько свойств  с  одинаковыми именами.
поэтому получается   следующее -

```
const obj = {
rock: {
    paper: ['Player 2 won!'],
},
paper: {
    rock: ['Player 1 won!'],
},
scissors: {
    rock: ['Player 2 won!'],
},};
```

, отсюда и проблема что  он всегда находит только  элементы с последним ключом.

Решить можно  например так

```js
const rps = (p1, p2) => {
    const rock = 'rock';
    const paper = 'paper';
    const scissors = 'scissors';
    const draw = 'Draw!';
    const p1win = 'Player 1 won!';
    const p2win = 'Player 2 won!';

    switch (true) {
        case p1 === p2: {
            return draw;
        }
        case (p1 === rock && p2 === scissors) ||
            (p1 === scissors && p2 === paper) ||
            (p1 === paper && p2 === rock): {
            return p1win;
        }
        default:
            return p2win;
    }
};

// console.log(rps('rock', 'rock'));
console.log(rps('rock', 'scissors'));
console.log(rps('rock', 'paper'));

console.log(rps('paper', 'scissors'));
console.log(rps('paper', 'rock'));

console.log(rps('scissors', 'paper'));
console.log(rps('scissors', 'rock'));
```